# Merging data from 2 promethues instances

Tags: prometheus

I have 2 instances of Prometheus, I need to merge them into 1. I'm looking for some manual on how to do this but I'm not sure what to google.

Can you just somehow marge 2 `/data` directories?

**EDIT-2.11.2020-**

I'm not talking about federation. Now that I learned more let me rephrase the question. This is about TSDB, not Prometheus service itself.

I'm using local storage and I have 2 directories `/data1` and `/data2` containing different historical data, I can use any with `--storage.tsdb.path` but I need to have both data historical data available, how do I do that?

This kind of relates to snapshots. Let's consider this scenario:

1. I have a snap done each month.
2. Something broke and now I have data from last week only.

So I have a `/data` directory that Prometheus is running with and `/backup` that have all data except the last 3 weeks.

All I could find on the web is that you can just run Prometheus with `--storage.tsdb.path=/backup` but this way I lose the most recent week, so what good is that?

Comment: Can't you just copy the files from `/backup` into `/data`?

Answer (score -1):

What you actually looking for is [Federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/)

You need to have one more Prometheus instance to federate your other two Prometheus instances. You can find detailed configuration in the documentation

Comment: No, I don't want to scrape metrics, I have 2 TSDBs with historical data and I want to merge them into one.

Comment: You can't merge data in prometheus, it is not supported.

Comment: Snapshots are used for backup. If you need to keep the data and merge with previous one, consider using the remote write interface to write it somewhere like InfluxDB. You can find more details ([here](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storage))